# Double for loop in 1 line to create a new tuple list

Tags: python, numpy

I have two sets of coordinates as numpy array. I would to create a new coordinate based on the first element of each set.

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]])
```

so I would like to get

> [(1,10), (3,30), (5, 50)]

I tried:

```
c = [(i[0], j[0]) for (i,j) in itertools.product(a,b)]
```

But itreturned:

> [(1, 10),  (1, 30),  (1, 50),  (3, 10),  (3, 30),  (3, 50),  (5, 10), 
>   (5, 30),  (5, 50)]

which is a nested loop. Is there a one line solution here?

Many thanks

J

Comment: Slice and stack - `np.c_[a[:,0],b[:,0]]`.

Comment: Use `zip` instead of `itertools.product`

Comment: Did you write the list of tuples in the result in opposite to the numpy-arrays in the input on purpose, so do you need this conversion of types, too, or do you just need only the extraction and rearrangement of the  described elements?

Comment: _yet another road to Rome_ `np.append(a, b, 1)[:, ::2]` ... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want result as tuples, first concatenate them along the second axis with [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html), view the result as an array of tuples and flatten the result with [`ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
np.c_[a[:,0],b[:,0]].view('i,i').ravel()
# array([(1, 10), (3, 30), (5, 50)], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4')])
```

---

Note that obtaining the result using numpy's vectorized operations will lead to huge benefits in terms of performance:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
b = np.array([[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]])
a = np.concatenate([a]*10000)
b = np.concatenate([b]*10000)

%timeit [(a_s[0], b_s[0]) for a_s, b_s in zip(a,b)]
# 19.2 ms ± 1.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit np.c_[a[:,0],b[:,0]].view('i,i').ravel()
# 82.1 µs ± 7.73 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is great. Didn't know concat method is more efficient than zip

Comment: Hi, again. my data is actually float rather than integer. When I tried view('f, f') it totally changes the value. Apparently I dont know how to use view correctly.

Comment: That again imo raises the question: do you really need a list of tuples and therefore the view/ravel-part here, or isn't a 2D-numpy array completely sufficient?

Comment: @J_yang you can achieve the same with `np.c_[a[:,0],b[:,0]].view('float,float').ravel()`

Answer (score 3):

Try the **built-in** function [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
print([(a_s[0], b_s[0]) for a_s, b_s in zip(a,b)])
# [(1, 10), (3, 30), (5, 50)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
temp_arr = np.concatenate([a[:,:,None],b[:,:,None]],axis=2)
temp_arr[:,0]
```

```py
array([[ 1, 10],
       [ 3, 30],
       [ 5, 50]])
```